# How to clear data from datatable using primefaces and java

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, jsf-2

I am trying to implement a datatable which is been called within the parent.xhtml and there are some operation with are carried on that data table like update, delete and cancel.
So when I am trying to edit my details under datatable and then we are trying to do cancel it used to keep the updated records even if I have not saved the records.
So these datatable is written in different xhtml file and it is called in parent.xhtml file due to which I am not able to perform cancel operation with is written inside parent.xhtml

The below logic is for datatable is written inside child.xhtml

Child.xhtml->

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" 
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"  xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"     xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
    <h3 class="pagesubheader">
        <span style="color: #CC0000; margin-left: 5px;">*&nbsp;</span>Welcome
    </h3>
    <p:panelGrid columns="1" style="width:100%;margin-left: 5px;" 
    rendered="#{pbgBean.tblList.tblVal}">   
    </p:panelGrid>
    <br />
    <p:panel class="psDetails" style="border:none !important;">
        <p:dataTable id="psTbl" var="flipPack"
            value="#{pbgBean.tblList.Details}"
            paginator="false" lazy="false" editable="true" editMode="cell"
            emptyMessage="empty" style="width:100%"
            rowKey="#{flipPack.Id}">
            <p:ajax event="cellEdit" listener="#{pbgBean.cellEdit}" />
            <p:column headerText="*ID"
                styleClass="custom-th custom-td custom-label customEditableCol"
                style="word-wrap:break-word !important;width:8%;">
                <p:cellEditor>
                    <f:facet name="output">
                        <p:outputLabel value="#{flipPack.Id}" />
                    </f:facet>
                    <f:facet name="input">
                        <p:inputText id="Id" value="#{flipPack.Id}"
                            style="width: 100% !important;"
                            maxlength="#{pbgBean.getMaxLength('ORDER_ID')}">
                            <p:ajax event="change" process="@this" update="messages" />
                        </p:inputText>
                    </f:facet>
                </p:cellEditor>
            </p:column>
            <p:column headerText="DESCRIPTION"
                styleClass="custom-th custom-td custom-label customEditableCol"
                style="word-wrap:break-word !important;width:15%;">
                <p:cellEditor>
                    <f:facet name="output">
                        <p:outputLabel value="#{flipPack.Description}" />
                    </f:facet>
                    <f:facet name="input">
                        <p:inputText id="Desc" value="#{flipPack.Description}"
                            maxlength="#{pbgBean.getMaxLength('DESC')}"
                            style="width: 100% !important;" converter="stringtrim">
                            <p:ajax event="change" process="@this" update="messages" />
                        </p:inputText>
                    </f:facet>
                </p:cellEditor>
            </p:column>
            <p:column headerText="Weight"
                styleClass="custom-th custom-td custom-label customEditableCol"
                style="word-wrap:break-word !important;width:15%;">
                <p:cellEditor>
                    <f:facet name="output">
                        <p:outputLabel value="#{flipPack.Weight}" />
                    </f:facet>
                    <f:facet name="input">
                        <p:inputText id="Weight" value="#{flipPack.Weight}"
                            style="width: 100% !important;" converter="stringtrim"
                            maxlength="#{pbgBean.getMaxLength('WT')}">
                            <p:ajax event="keyup"
                                listener="#{pbgBean.autoPopulateWeight(flipPack)}"
                                process="@this" update="flipPackForm:WeightD" resetValues="true" />
                        </p:inputText>
                    </f:facet>
                </p:cellEditor>
            </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
</p:panel>
</ui:composition>
```

The above child.xhtml is called under parent.xhtml->

```
<h:panelGroup id="flipPackBlock">
                            <h:panelGroup id="flipPackContentData" rendered="#{pbgBean.tblList.simFlag}">
                            <ui:include src="child.xhtml">
                                    <ui:param name="pbgBean" value="#{pbgBean}" />
                            </ui:include>
                            </h:panelGroup>
                            </h:panelGroup>
```

Logic for cancelBtn->

```
<p:commandButton id="cancelBtn" action="#{pbgBean.cancelPbg}" value="CANCEL"
                                        style="width: 170px; height: 37px;" update=":flipPackForm:edit" class="btn-red rounded-corner"
                                        oncomplete="PF('DetailsWidgetvar').hide();" process="@this">
                                        <p:resetInput target="returnWrapper" /></p:commandButton>
```

Java logic for cancelBtn :

```
public void cancelPbg() {
   if (previousDetails != null && CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(previousDetails.getErrorKeysList())) {
       for (ErrorMessage error : previousDetails.getErrorKeysList()) {
               GenUtil.updateUIComponents(error.getKey(), true);
           }
           
        }
   if (flipDetails != null && CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(flipDetails.getErrorKeysList())) {
       for (ErrorMessage error : flipDetails.getErrorKeysList()) {
               GenUtil.updateUIComponents(error.getKey(), true);
            }
           
        }      
   previousDetails = new flipPack();
   flipDetails = new flipPack();
   RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().addCallbackParam("done", true);
}
```